# Android getting image from gallery freezes app after updating google play services

Tags: android, android-intent, gradle, gallery

I know this is very weird but probably ever since i updated google play services then when i try getting an image from the gallery using intents like this :

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
 startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
```

my app freezes forever and i get a black screen whether i choose an image or cancel the intent operation , and to be sure i have reverted my gradle file back and then everything worked fine!

my old gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
android {

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 8
    versionName "3.0.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_CRASHLYTICS", "false"
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }

}
lintOptions {

    checkReleaseBuilds false
    //abortOnError false

}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile project(':viewPagerIndicatorLibrary')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1-with-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.3.jar')
compile files('libs/PdfViewer.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:+'
//    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
//    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3"
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava-collections:r03'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
}
```

after updating my gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
android {

packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
    exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
    exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
}
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.myapp"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 8
    versionName "3.0.0"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
    debug {
        buildConfigField "boolean", "USE_CRASHLYTICS", "false"
        ext.enableCrashlytics = false
    }

}
lintOptions {

    checkReleaseBuilds false
    //abortOnError false

}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile project(':viewPagerIndicatorLibrary')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.1-with-sources.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-4.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpclient-cache-4.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/httpcore-4.3.1.jar')
compile files('libs/httpmime-4.3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/gcm.jar')
compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.3.jar')
compile files('libs/PdfViewer.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:percent:+'
//    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
//    compile "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3"
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.guava:guava-collections:r03'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
compile 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

as for the gradle project file , i only changed this

```
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0-beta2'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
```

to this :

```
   dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.+'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
 }
```

i know apparently this looks like it has nothing to do with the gallery intent , but that what actually happens.

also there isn't anything notable in the logcat to define the problem , the app just freezes !

Answer (score 0):

I have used only the libraries i need from the play service like this :

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:9.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.0.2'
```

this resolved my problem , but still this issue needs explanation and investigation from google.

Answer (score 0):

I updated to 9.2.0 and now it works, but it's a strange issue.